# Festival: is possible to get the output on stdout of an interactive command?

Tags: festival

If I run

```
festival
```

The interactive console is opened and I run a command, for example

```
(doc cdddr)
```

Is possible to get the output on stdout?
I have tried

```
echo "(doc cdddr)"|festival
```

and

```
echo "(doc cdddr)"|festival -b
```

but no output on console

I also tried this nice method(working with tftp and some other commands)

```
festival -b <<EOF
(doc cdddr)
EOF
```

but no output on console

edit 1: a little progress

This command show the output on console

```
festival <<EOF
(system " cat < file.txt")
EOF
```

but I'm interested to make the festival shell to "execute" the contents of file.txt, someone know some Unix command which read and execute the lines from "file.txt"? The file "file.txt" doesn't contain shell bash command so the answer "sh file.txt" is not correct.

Comment: According to the manpage `festival <(echo '(doc car)')` or `festival <<<'(doc car)'` should work (assuming a shell like bash or ksh).

Comment: I have tried both, one give me no output, the other open festival console